# "Usare fare qualcosa" versus "Essere solito fare qualcosa"

Tags: idioms, difference

So che l'espressione "usare fare qualcosa" significa "essere solito fare qualcosa", ma non so se tutte e due le espressioni si usino con la stessa frequenza o abbiano usi diversi. Sapreste dirmi qualcosa al riguardo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La differenza tra le due espressioni è minima; cercherò di essere più chiaro facendo degli esempi.

**"Usare fare qualcosa"**

"Nel nostro paese si usa festeggiare ogni terza Domenica del mese."

**"Essere solito/i far qualcosa"**

"Sono solito fare il bucato dopo pranzo."

*Entrambe* le espressioni indicano un'azione ripetuta nel tempo. Tuttavia, la prima è più utilizzata per parlare di consuetudini e/o tradizioni, mentre la seconda è più utilizzata per parlare di abitudini personali.

---

È bene notare che, come la maggior parte delle espressioni linguistiche, esse possono essere intercambiabili, in quanto entrambe hanno, come detto precedentemente, lo scopo di indicare un'azione ripetuta.

Comment: Capisco. Dunque, l'esempio di egreg (_Per colazione uso bere caffè_) non è tanto frequente?

Comment: Credo siano più frequenti le espressioni *"Sono solito bere il caffè per colazione."* o *"Per colazione solitamente bevo caffè."* Poi, l'abitudine ad usare una o l'altra espressione varia in base alla regione geografica, dove si è soliti usare espressioni più o meno caratteristiche. Poi ci sono le eccezioni: io e @egreg attualmente viviamo nella stessa città, eppure lui è uso utilizzare l'espressione "io sono uso fare...", mentre io uso "sono solito fare...". Potere dell'italiano! P.s.: if you prefer to have replies in English, I'll translate them.

Comment: Non è necessario: capisco bene l'italiano.

Comment: @uomoinverde Fai riferimento a [questo](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-allow-questions-answers-to-be-in-italian). Se la domanda è posta in italiano rispondi in italiano, se è in inglese rispondi in inglese.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of "usare fare qualcosa". Actually it *sounds* wrong, which usually means it is wrong, because the "wrong" feeling usually indicates that the person in question (in this case, me) has never heard of such combinations of words.

I live near Milan, so maybe it's not used here but elsewhere in Italy, but I wouldn't have my hopes high. I am pretty convinced "usare fare qualcosa" is wrong.

On the other hand, "essere **soliti** (not *solito*) fare qualcosa" is a common, used phrase.

EDIT: It seems "usare fare qualcosa" is not, from a grammatical point of view, incorrect. It sounds strange because nobody actually uses it, since "solito" is so much more common.

Comment: *Per colazione uso bere caffè*: it doesn't sound wrong, does it?

Comment: @Con7e: But you can find the expression "usare fare qualcosa" at dictionaries. Have a look at [Vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/usare/). This may mean that it is a very infrequent expression and this is the reason of my question. On the other side, I guess that the use of "essere solito", "essere solita" or "essere soliti" would depend on the gender and number of the subject of the sentence. For instance, I would say "Sono solita prendere un caffè a colazione" since I am a woman.

Comment: If a question was asked in Italian you should answer it *in Italian*. If a question is asked in English you should answer it in English. Mixing the two doesn't work very well because the OP may not be able to understand your reply (think of someone that just started learning Italian, or an Italian that doesn't speak English. Both may ask a question here). See the [relevant topic](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-allow-questions-answers-to-be-in-italian) on meta.